# Is it possible to manually increase the precision of a double as a bit string through calculations

Tags: c#, math, floating-point, double, precision

In order to create a floating point number from a decimal value, we need to have a sign bit, and exponent, and a mantissa.

Double precision uses 11 exponent bits, and 52 mantissa bits.

Let's say we want to store 0.3. We can find the mantissa by doing the following:

```
0.3 * 2 = 0.6 => 0
0.6 * 2 = 1.2 => 1
0.2 * 2 = 0.4 => 0
0.4 * 2 = 0.8 => 0
0.8 * 2 = 1.6 => 1
0.6 * 2 = 1.2 => 1
...
Answer:
01001100110011...
```

In C# I can do this with the following code:

```cs
double value = 0.3;
StringBuilder bitString = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < 53; i++)
{
    value *= 2;
    if (value >= 1)
    {
        bitString.Append("1");
        value--;
    }
    else
    {
        bitString.Append("0");
    }
}
```

1. Is it possible to take an existing mantissa from a double, and **continue** this process to find further bits? I know this won't work for certain values, but what if I have an exact number like 0.123, and I know all the remaining digits are 0. 0.1230000000...
2. My code above seems to have a problem. Since I am using a double for my multiplication, I only have 15-17 digits of precision. It is possible during my multiply by 2 situation to be slightly off ending the number of bits I can accurately store. Is there away around this without needing a bigger type like System.Decimal?

The goal here is to end up with a bit string, that contains **more than 53 bits** of valid data.

Comment: You want `decimal` precision but don't want to use `decimal`? That's quite weird to be honest.

Comment: @Aybe I want a bit string of arbitrary precision. Decimal would give me 96-bits of precision, but what if I wanted 128, or 256?

Comment: Search the web for `c# arbitrary precision decimal`, you'll find quite a couple of implementations.